# What is wrong with this crontab entry?

Tags: linux, cron

This entry does not work:

`*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -o /tmp/tmp-cron-output -O /tmp/tmp-cron http://domain/stations/system/cron-jobs/shipping-update >> /dev/null`

This entry DOES work:

`*/1 * * * * echo "test" > /tmp/tmp-test`

If I type the following directly in the command line from SSH, it DOES work:

`/usr/bin/wget -o /tmp/tmp-cron-output -O /tmp/tmp-cron http://domain/stations/system/cron-jobs/shipping-update >> /dev/null`

I do not understand why it is not working.  I was doing something earlier that was working that was basically the same concept, and then I changed a lot of things and I'm now stuck..

**EDIT**

The problem is it was adding a %0D to the end of the URL which rooted to when I was generating my file to import into cron I was adding \r\n between each line.  I changed it to \n and and it now works and no longer adds %0D to the end of the URL wget is attempting to fetch.

Comment: What if you don't forward the output to the `/dev/null`? Have you checked mail for the given user?

Comment: Removal of the forward yielded the same results.  Also mail isn't installed?  Will I still get mail?

Comment: For debugging run your command with `> /tmp/log.txt 2>&1` instead of `>> /dev/null` and see if you get an error. Do you happen to have a proxy setting in your shell environment?

Comment: You can use `env -i sh -c '/usr/bin/wget ..... '` to more accurately emulate the environment cron runs the command in. That lets you try out e.g. Marcus' good suggestion without having to add it to crontab and waiting.

Comment: It is generating the output files without the /dev/null now, but it is returning 404?  The file is there and I can download it directly from the ssh terminal.

Comment: I think I'd create an .sh file and put all the commands in there if it was so long.

Comment: Has this got anything to do with PHP at all? Removing tag!